# Does alert('some message') can make an impact in a callback function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, webcam-capture

I had written a callback function to capture the snapshot of running video using html5 video control and canvas. 
I used a `for` loop to iterate and  call the same callback function take the burst capture. 
If i add `alert('')` in the callback , the video in the background rerendering when alert message display, the burst snap shot works fine as taking diff photos(frames/images of the running video). But when I removed the `alert('')` , the video does not run in the background and the bursted images are the same instead of different.

The code

```
for (var i = 0; i < burstcount; i++) {
        var wcam = Webcam;
            wcam.burst_snap(function (dataurl, id) {
                var arrayindex = passedName + "_" + id;
                imgid = imgid + i;
                alert(dataurl);
                burstcapturedata[arrayindex] = dataurl;
            }, i);
            var j = 0;
            while (j < 10000000000) {
                j++;
            }
    }
    DisplayBurstedImages();
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you have an asynchronous call and you are treating it as a synchronous one. But without code, I can not verify that.

Comment: @epascarello - code added , can u have a look at it,

Comment: Looks like burst_snap is asynchronous...Not sure what `burst_snap` is... And that while loop is bad practice.

Comment: @epascarello  - i removed the while loop , its only for making the current execution to hold a bit, i used sleep(milliseconds) , one of javascript guy's idea to hold an application for a period of time. do i need to post the burst_snap code as well

Comment: What is Webcam and burst_snap? Is it triggered a set number of times? When is it done?

Comment: its triggered from a button onClick and upto the burstcount is reached where burstcount is the count to take snaps continuosly.The Webcam is a library provided by a guy to capture webcam snapshots.its an singleton object. the burst_snap is the method that called inside the Webcam library

Comment: So how many images are you waiting for before you really want to call DisplayBurstedImages?

Comment: around 3 , but i think of upto six.

Comment: Is that value in `burstcount`??

Comment: yes , its the burst limit , currently i gave it to 3. can be given upto 6 though

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  actually. Alert holds next execution of code. 
If your code works with alert it means that you require delay. 
Try `setTimeout` or put the code in the correct place where everything is getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it needs time for binding video. you can use setTimeout function for delay.

```
var delay =100;

setTimeout(function () {/*your function*/ }, delay);

delay = delay + 300;
```

Comment: i tried it just now cos lot of guys suggested that , no use .. i cant figure out the reason yet, the alert somehow do the magic here, i need some seriuos explaination abt this

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to look something like this:

```
 var wcam = Webcam;
 var cnt = 0;
 wcam.burst_snap(function(dataurl, id) {
   var arrayindex = passedName + "_" + id;  //you do not have an array if this is the key
   imgid = imgid + cnt;  //no clue what this is for
   cnt++;
   burstcapturedata[arrayindex] = dataurl;
   if (cnt===burstcount) {
     DisplayBurstedImages();
   }
 }, 100);  //no clue what that value is supposed to be
```

Comment: i tried the code , but it getting called only once not up to the burstcount(meant 3). i have not used the for loop , should i use for loop too?

Comment: Does burst_snap only call one time or does it work multiple times? If I have an api it would be easy to help. Without it, I am just guessing what this stuff does.

Comment: the burst_snap getting called only one time . i am not using any loops , should i use for loop. the Webcamjs is the api i am using for capturing images https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs
i copied and pasted the snap function of the api as burst_snap for my understanding.